# HTML5 draggable disables text fields

Tags: html, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to implement html5 drag and drop, but i want the text fields inside a draggable area to act as they normally would. Right now the input does not react to mouse events. See the example below:

```
<div draggable="true">
    <input type="text" draggable="false" />
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Hvm4g/

How would i fix this? Please don't offer jQuery. If i wanted to do it in javascript - i wouldn't be asking this question now.

Thanks for your thoughts